# An application of Fubini’s theorem on Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Given $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and we denote the Fourier transform of $f$ by $\widehat{f}$.

I want to prove that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(x)g(x)~dx= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\widehat{g}(x)~dx.$$

Here’s my attempt:
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(x)g(x)~dx=&\int _{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\{\int _{\mathbb{R}^n} f(t)e^{-2\pi it\cdot x}~dt\right\}g(x)dx\\
=&\int _{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\{\int _{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x)f(t)e^{-2\pi it\cdot x}~dt\right\}dx\\
{\color{red}{=}}&\int _{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x)f(t)e^{-2\pi it\cdot x}dx\right\}~dt\\
=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x)e^{-2\pi it\cdot x}dx\right\}f(t)~dt\\
=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(t)\widehat{g}(t)~dt\\
=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\widehat{g}(x)dx.
\end{align}

In the third equation I used Fubini’s theorem. But **here’s something that I’m not sure**: if we want to apply Fubini’s theorem, then $F(x,t):= g(x)f(t)e^{-2\pi it\cdot x}$ must be $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ integrable. But I was stuck when trying to prove that $F(x,t)$ is integrable. Could you give me some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n}|F(x,t)| \lambda(dx,dt)$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n}|g(x) f(t)| \lambda(dx,dt)$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g(x)||f(t)| \lambda(dx) \lambda(dt)$$
$$= \Vert g \Vert_1 \Vert f \Vert_1 < \infty$$

by Fubini for positive functions.

Comment: But where is $e^{-2\pi it\cdot x}$?

Comment: $|e^{i\theta}| = 1$ when $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "Fubini for positive functions" is commonly known as Tonelli's Theorem...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Did you downvote?

Comment: no.............

Comment: Alright. Sorry for asking. Have a good day/night!

Comment: I don’t see why people are downvoting this answer.

Comment: I can promise you it is correct. Probably made someone unhappy on this website.

Comment: @ε-δ +1 from me. I tried to do it when accepting this answer, but I was told that I didn’t have enough reputations to upvote since I was new : )

Comment: Appreciated! I'd return the favour by upvoting your post but I already did :)

Comment: Thank you. I’ve just asked a new question. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3700551/792898) if you might kindly want to have a look. Have a nice day!